# How to pass multiple values in node express options qs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my node.js api I am trying to pass multiple values into the fields `tracking` and `carrier` , but I have been unsuccessful. I am able to do this with single values (1 tracking number for `tracking` and 1 carrier code for `carrier`), but not for multiple values. I feel like there should be a loop involve, but maybe I am incorrect in stating this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Index.html**

```
<script>

    function UserParams() {
        console.log('UserParams')

        var trackingNumber = ['123', '456'];
        var carrierCode = ['usps', 'fedex'];

        var url = '/api/tracking/retrieve/';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: { tracking: trackingNumber, carrier: carrierCode },
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function (e) {
                console.log('Error Message: ', e.message);
            }
        });

    }

</script>
```

**Controller.js**

```
    app.get("/api/tracking/retrieve", (req, res) => {

    var carrier = req.query.carrier;
    var tracking = req.query.tracking;

    console.log('carrier array', carrier);
    console.log('tracking array', tracking);

    var options = {
        method: "GET",
        url: 'https://api.example.com/v1/tracking',
        qs: { carrier_code: carrier, tracking_number: tracking },
        headers:
            {
                'api-key': process.env.SECRET_KEY_SE,
                'accept': 'application/json'
            }
    }

    console.log("Url: ", req.url);
    console.log("Query: ", req.query);
    res.send("ok");

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('BODY', body)
            var trackingData = JSON.parse(body)
            table = 'tracking_table';
            col = [
                'user_id',
                'tracking_number',
                'carrier_code',
                 ];
            val = [
                user_id,
                trackingData.tracking_number,
                options.qs.carrier_code,
                   ];
            main.create(table, col, val, function (data) {
                res.json({
                    id: data.insertId,
                    user_id: user_id,
                    tracking_number: data.tracking_number,
                    carrier_code: data.carrier_code,
              });
            })
        }
    })

})
```

Result in terminal:

```
carrier array [ 'usps', 'fedex' ]
tracking array [ '123', '456' ]
Url:  /api/tracking/retrieve/?tracking%5B%5D=123&tracking%5B%5D=456&carrier%5B%5D=usps&carrier%5B%5D=fedex
Query:  { tracking: [ '123', '456' ],
carrier: [ 'usps', 'fedex' ] }
```

Edit: Edited question to include further context.

Comment: What you are getting in tracking & carrier variables with multiple values?

Comment: Base on your code. '9361289691090998780245,784644233438' is multiple values. and '9361289691090998780245' is a single value. Right?

Comment: @ChuongTran Yes, that is correct. I edited my question for better context.

Comment: @Kishan get as in what is the response I get when I run the code?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the backend is you can try simply using arrays for this purpose, e.g.

```
var tracking = ['9361289691090998780245','784644233438'];
var carrier =  ['usps','fedex'];

options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: 'https://api.example.com/v1/tracking',
    qs: { tracking_number: tracking, carrier_code: carrier },
    headers:
        {
            'api-key': process.env.SECRET_KEY_SE,
            'accept': 'application/json'
        }
}

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) console.error("An error occurred: ", error);
    console.log("body: ", body);
});
```

If this is served by Express, the query string will be parsed correctly, e.g.

```
app.get("/api/tracking/retrieve", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Url: ", req.url);
    console.log("Query: ", req.query);
    res.send("ok");
});
```

This is what would be logged by Express;

```
Url:  /api/tracking/retrieve?tracking_number%5B0%5D=9361289691090998780245&tracking_number%5B1%5D=784644233438&carrier_code%5B0%5D=usps&carrier_code%5B1%5D=fedex
Query:  { tracking_number: [ '9361289691090998780245', '784644233438' ], carrier_code: [ 'usps', 'fedex' ] }
```

Of course it depends on the API provider, so it might be worth seeing if they have documentation on how parameters should be formatted.

Comment: I will try this later to see if this works. It looks like you took the variables out, making them global. I edited my original code in the question to provide further context. Would var tracking become var tracking = req.query.tracking if I am going to be sending the values from the front end to the back end?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you use an array for this purpose, then the variable res.query.tracking should also be an array!

Comment: I have adjusted the code at the top to reflect the code I am working with. I am am able to get the result you had said would happen, but I ran into another issue. If I use 1 tracking number and 1 carrier in the above example the api will return the desired json, but when I use 2 tracking numbers and two carrier codes I do not recieve any information from the api. Do I need a loop in there?

Comment: It looks like you probably will need a loop to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change string tracking & carrier to **array** with function **split**

```
app.get('/api/tracking/retrieve', function (req, res) {
  options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: 'https://api.example.com/v1/tracking',
      qs: { tracking_number: tracking.split(','), carrier_code: carrier.split(',') },
      headers:
          {
              'api-key': process.env.SECRET_KEY_SE,
              'accept': 'application/json'
          }
  }

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
 })
});
```